# Loader spinner not using full view port height html css

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular-material

[image: this output I am facing currently how do I get full viewport background instead of this half portion of my loader background please help]

```css
.sub-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 45px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-container">

<div class="spinner">

<mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate" diameter="75" strokeWidth="5">
</mat-progress-spinner>

</div>

</div>
```

This is my source code for representing the material spinner in the background of my right container's div how can I achieve full viewport height for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the `.sub-container`'s `width` (like so)?

```css
.sub-container {
    width: auto;
    padding: 45px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #d9d9d9;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-container">

<div class="spinner">

<mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate" diameter="75" strokeWidth="5">
</mat-progress-spinner>

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I need 100vh height for the sub-container which is basically the right container which is scrollable and the left part is fixed.

Comment: So the left menu is inside of the `.sub-container`?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide examples of how you have that code implemented as well?